# Microsoft Office changes network file to read only

Tags: microsoft-office

Whenever I have a network file open and the network connection is reset or changed, for instance due to closing my laptop in dock and removing it from dock, the open files are changed to read only. Thus, even when the network is re-established I'm not able to just continue working in the same file, I have to save it as a NEW file name. This drives me completely nuts. Any solution to this ridiculous behaviour?

Comment: What's the file type or application?

Comment: Word, Excel, Powerpoint, all the Office applications.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: What's the environment of the network location?

Comment: @adampski I'm on Office 2010, but I'm not sure if I understand your last comment. It's my work network, which is kind of slow (no idea why).

Comment: The network location of which the file resides on, is it a Windows server? The reason why I asked was so I could provide a tailored answer. Did I solve your problem by force closing the open file in Computer Management?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of server our stuff resides at. As to solving the problem: I'd like to avoid the entire point with having to close the files and reopen the previously saved version. It would be nice to avoid the entire "I can see you logged off there for a second; now let me please open all your network files in Read Only mode".

Answer (score 1):

If the network location is a Windows environment you can force close the previous session's resource via `Computer Management` > `System Tools` > `Shared Folders` > `Open Files`.

[image]

You can also use collabrative features/settings or shared documents within most Office documents, this might release the locked resource situation but isn't appropriately handling the problem via closing the previous session. But if my first suggestion didn't work, let me know which version you're using and I'll try to taylor my answer by giving this a go.